# how to show hide single area in multiple div

Tags: javascript, jquery

we have one problem in code, in my code function there is main div area and inside this we have two radio button when we change or select radio there is two section one is for textarea and one for file up load button, when we click they show and hide.

please find the link of my code:- https://jsfiddle.net/bharat_negi/bw6uw9ah/

jquery code :-

```
function changeCheck(){       
      $('.questionBlock').on('change', 'input[type=radio][name=gender]', function() {   
        var changeOption = $(this).closest('.radioArea').attr("data-id");
        console.log(changeOption);

        if (this.value == 'Image') {
            $('.textArea').show();
            $('.browseArea').hide();
        }
        else if (this.value == 'Text') {
            $('.textArea').hide();
            $('.browseArea').show();
        }

      });

    }
```

Comment: what exactly do you need to do? Hide only 1 field whenever you click the radio button? It's really hard to understand what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Comment: this what you want ? https://jsfiddle.net/bw6uw9ah/1/

Comment: yes, but radio selection one for each block, currently it is working for all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.You need target the element of textarea from the `closest` parent otherwise its target all the texarea element.That why its hiding all the textarea and choose buttons.And also change the matching `if` with `Text` else with `Image`

```js
changeCheck();

function changeCheck() {
  $('.questionBlock').on('change', 'input[type=radio][name=gender]', function() {
    var changeOption = $(this).closest('.radioArea').attr("data-id");
    console.log(changeOption);

    if (this.value == 'Text') {
      $(this).closest('.questionBlock').find('.textArea').show();
      $(this).closest('.questionBlock').find('.browseArea').hide();
    } else if (this.value == 'Image') {
      $(this).closest('.questionBlock').find('.textArea').hide();
      $(this).closest('.questionBlock').find('.browseArea').show();
    }

  });

}
```

```css
.questionBlock {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.questionBlock .alloption {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}

.questionBlock .text {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 10%;
}

.questionBlock .radioArea {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 20%;
}

.questionBlock .textArea {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 70%;
}

.questionBlock .browseArea {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 70%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="questionBlock">
  <div class="text">Option 1</div>
  <div class="radioArea" data-id="upload1">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Image" checked> Image
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Text"> Text
  </div>
  <div class="textArea">
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50"> At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.</textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="browseArea">
    <input type="file" name="" class="" id="">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="questionBlock">
  <div class="text">Option 2</div>
  <div class="radioArea" data-id="upload2">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Image" checked> Image
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Text"> Text
  </div>
  <div class="textArea">
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50"> At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.</textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="browseArea">
    <input type="file" name="" class="" id="">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="questionBlock">
  <div class="text">Option 3</div>
  <div class="radioArea" data-id="upload3">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Image" checked> Image
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Text"> Text
  </div>
  <div class="textArea">
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50"> At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.</textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="browseArea">
    <input type="file" name="" class="" id="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find working jsfiddle here without so much changes to your code

```
function changeCheck(){       
          $('.questionBlock').on('change', 'input[type=radio]', function() {    

            if (this.value == 'Image') {
        console.log($(this).parent())
                $(this).parents('.questionBlock').find('.textArea').hide();
                  $(this).parents('.questionBlock').find('.browseArea').show();
            }
            else if (this.value == 'Text') {
                $(this).parents('.questionBlock').find('.textArea').show();
                            $(this).parents('.questionBlock').find('.browseArea').hide();
            }

          });

        }
```

[Multiple checkbox toggle with image and textarea](https://jsfiddle.net/bw6uw9ah/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is updated jquery function:

changeCheck();

```
    function changeCheck(){       
      $('.questionBlock').on('change', 'input[type=radio][name=gender]', function() {   
        var changeOption = $(this).closest('.radioArea').attr("data-id");
        console.log(changeOption);

        if (this.value == 'Image') {
            $(this).closest('.questionBlock').find('.textArea').show();
            $(this).closest('.questionBlock').find('.browseArea').hide();
        }
        else if (this.value == 'Text') {
            $(this).closest('.questionBlock').find('.textArea').hide();
          $(this).closest('.questionBlock').find('.browseArea').show();
        }

      });

    }
```

I have used `$(this).closest('.questionBlock')` to get the relevant textarea and fileupload elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here  `$(this).parent().closest('div')` will get the 'radioArea' div then you call the `.next()` it will retrieve next div after the 'radioArea' which is 'textArea' div so in this way you can perform show or hide functionality corresponding to the item that you clicked.

```
  $(this).parent().closest('div').next().next().show();//show browseArea div
  $(this).parent().closest('div').next().hide(); //hide textArea div
```

```js
changeCheck();

  function changeCheck(){    
    $('.questionBlock').on('change', 'input[type=radio][name=gender]', function() { 
     var changeOption = $(this).closest('.radioArea').attr("data-id");
     console.log(changeOption);

     if (this.value == 'Image') {
        $(this).parent().closest('div').next().next().show();//show browseArea div
        $(this).parent().closest('div').next().hide(); //hide textArea div
         
      }
      else if (this.value == 'Text') {
         $(this).parent().closest('div').next().next().hide(); //hide browseArea div
         $(this).parent().closest('div').next().show(); //show textArea div
      }

    });

  }
```

```css
.questionBlock{ float: left; margin: 0; padding: 10px 0; width: 100%; display: flex;}
.questionBlock .alloption{float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; clear: both;}
.questionBlock .text{ display: inline-block; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 10%;}
.questionBlock .radioArea{ display: inline-block; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 20%;}
.questionBlock .textArea{ display: inline-block; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 70%;}
.questionBlock .browseArea{ display: inline-block; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 70%; display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="questionBlock">
    <div class="text">Option 1</div>
    <div class="radioArea" data-id="upload1">
     <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Image" checked> Image 
       <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Text"> Text
    </div>
    <div class="textArea">
     <textarea rows="4" cols="50"> At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="browseArea">
     <input type="file" name="" class="" id="">
    </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="questionBlock">
    <div class="text">Option 2</div>
    <div class="radioArea" data-id="upload2">
     <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Image" checked> Image 
       <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Text"> Text
    </div>
    <div class="textArea">
     <textarea rows="4" cols="50"> At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="browseArea">
     <input type="file" name="" class="" id="">
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="questionBlock">
    <div class="text">Option 3</div>
    <div class="radioArea" data-id="upload3">
     <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Image" checked> Image 
       <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Text"> Text
    </div>
    <div class="textArea">
     <textarea rows="4" cols="50"> At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="browseArea">
     <input type="file" name="" class="" id="">
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Is this is your expected output?